# Cant link css to document, bug?

Tags: html, css

Hello i cant link `css` file to my `index.html` in 3 out of 5 browsers? its very weird that it only works in `internet explorer/edge`. It all works for all browsers if i do a style tag instead but i want to link it to a file!!! Down bellow i have my code and also a screenshot of the browsers.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        xd
    </header>
    <nav>
        xd
    </nav>
    <section>
        xd
    </section>
    <aside>
        xd
    </aside>
    <footer>
        xd
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

.

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body { 
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

header {
    background-color: #707070;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

nav {
    background-color: #C9BFBF;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

section {
    background-color: #ABABAB;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

aside {
    background-color: #C9C9C9;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

footer {
    background-color: #707070;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

[image to all browsers response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roqyk.png)

[image]

Comment: What do you see in the devtools?

Comment: in chrome for example i see the external file with all it content in Sorces

Comment: What do you see in the console & network tab?

Comment: nothing in console and on network idk nothing i guess

Comment: Does this happen with just this one particular CSS file, or any arbitrary CSS file?

Comment: i solved it with the help of @ludwig

Answer (score -3, accepted):

try checking your html install folder, sometimes I have this problem and I see some things that should not be in there. does not help every time but sometimes it does. :)

Comment: Okey where is html folder located? maby in system32 or????

Comment: it's not the same for everyone, if you don't remember where you choose the location try reinstalling and choosing a good spot for your little folder.

Comment: This is nonsense. HTML isn't a program that is installed. It's a document format.